# select from table between dates and count duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table named `tblOrders`

```
| ID  | name    | email      | amount  | date       |
+-----+---------+------------+---------+------------+
| 1   | danny   | dan@email  | $10.00  | 06/01/2015 |
| 2   | bryan   | bra@email  | $50.00  | 06/01/2015 |
| 3   | jenny   | jen@email  | $20.00  | 06/02/2015 |
| 4   | gabby   | gab@email  | $35.00  | 06/02/2015 |
| 5   | lisa    | lisa@email | $12.00  | 06/03/2015 |
| 6   | don     | don@email  | $23.00  | 06/04/2015 |
| 7   | danny   | dan@email  | $22.00  | 06/04/2015 |
| 8   | bryan   | bra@email  | $55.00  | 06/05/2015 |
| 9   | danny   | dan@email  | $69.00  | 06/20/2015 |
| 10  | danny   | dan@email  | $49.00  | 06/25/2015 |
```

I want to select from `tblOrders` between date `06/03/2015` and `06/25/03/2015`
and then count the number of repeated customers I have.

Select between date `06/03/2015` and `06/25/03/2015` provides

```
| ID | name  | email      | amount | date        |
+----+-------+------------+--------+-------------+
| 5  | lisa  | lisa@email | $12.00 | 06/03/2015  |
| 6  | don   | don@email  | $23.00 | 06/04/2015  |
| 7  | danny | dan@email  | $22.00 | 06/04/2015  |
| 8  | bryan | bra@email  | $55.00 | 06/05/2015  |
| 9  | danny | dan@email  | $69.00 | 06/20/2015  |
| 10 | danny | dan@email  | $49.00 | 06/25/2015  |
```

Then checking by `email` from those records if exist in all `tblOrders` and count
This should provide count of `2` as there are 2 customers between those dates that ordered before.

How can I achieve that with one SQL query?

I'm using Access database and ASP classic

My current code is

```
ReturnCustomers = 0
 Set rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
 SQL = ("select ID,Email,OrderDate from tblOrders Where OrderDate between #"&date1&"# and "&date2&";")
 rs.Open SQL,Cnn,3,1
 Do while Not rs.EOF

  Set rsCount = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
  SQL = ("select ID from tblOrders Where Email='"&rs("Email")&"' and Not ID="&rs("ID")&";")
  rsCount.Open SQL,Cnn,3,1
  IF Not rsCount.EOF Then
   ReturnCustomers = ReturnCustomers+1
  End IF
  rsCount.Close
  Set rsCount = Nothing

 rs.MoveNext
 Loop
 rs.Close
 Set rs = Nothing
 response.write ReturnCustomers
```

How can I do this one in 1 SQL query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want repeat customers --- those who made a purchase during the target date range and also made a purchase sometime before the start of that date range.

First create a query to retrieve those unique customers:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT o1.email
FROM
    tblOrders AS o1
    INNER JOIN tblOrders AS o2
    ON o1.email = o2.email
WHERE
    (o1.date Between #2015-6-3# And #2015-6-25#)
    AND o2.date < #2015-6-3#;
```

However you actually want only the count of those customers.  So you can use the first query as a subquery and derive the count from that:

```sql
SELECT Count(sub.email) AS CountOfemail
FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT o1.email
        FROM
            tblOrders AS o1
            INNER JOIN tblOrders AS o2
            ON o1.email = o2.email
        WHERE
            (o1.date Between #2015-6-3# And #2015-6-25#)
            AND o2.date < #2015-6-3#
    ) AS sub;
```

Answer (score 0):

you are not looking for duplicates. If you want to find out who ordered between date #06/03/2015# to #06/25/03/2015# and ordered before #06/03/2015# , your query should be like :

```
 select distinct name, email from tblorders o
 where date >=#06/03/2015# and date < #06/25/03/2015#
 and exists (select * from tblorders p where p.email = o.email
     and p.date <#06/03/2015# )
```

Also please specify your sql system.

Comment: Hi, thanks I'll try this one. I edit my post -- I'm using access database and asp classic. does it works for it as well ?

Comment: I think ms access supports "Exists" but I am not familiar with that. If it's not working, post your code and I believe people familiar with MS Access will come to help.

Comment: i have tried this one, it doesn't working.. I will edit my post with my current code it might help someone it understand what i need.. thanks for your assistance

Comment: you need change the column names to yours.